# XPages - parameters for @WarningMessage?

Tags: javascript, xpages, lotus, xpages-ssjs

I have a question in relation to @WarningMessage: When I call a script directly from a button on my XPage, it works fine. However, I would like to first call a pop-up dialog from a button (using xe:dialog), call some SSJS from a button on the xe:dialog, and from the SSJS have @WarningMessage display an error mesage on the XPage (not display an error in the xe:dialog as currently happens). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, as with most everything else, this is possible with XPages, just not easy or straight forward. What I would do is create a client side script block which triggers an SSJS event on the XPage as the dialog is closed. That SSJS determines if the warning is needed and sets it after the dialog is closed, or in the OnComplete part of the event call in the CSJS code.

I am sure that there are other ways to do it using beans and Java code which would be faster and more robust.

Comment: Basically what happens is that SSJS code is run from the xe:dialog. This SSJS validates the XPage. If validation fails, the error dialog on the XPages should appear.

Answer (score 1):

The Extension Library dialog accepts a parameter for the component that should be refreshed after the dialog is closed. So you should be able to add an xp:messages control to a panel (or div), set that id as the refreshId on the closeDialog method, still use @WarningMessage in your SSJS and display the message.

Alternatively, the warning message probably just shows content with a specific styleClass defined. So your SSJS could write to a normal Computed Field control that has the same styleClass defined. Then include that Computed Field in the area to refresh after closing the dialog.